# how to use a method with 2 parameters in my lambda expression

Tags: linq, lambda, expression

I use linq to access a table from my DB using Entity Framework

```
MyDBEntities context = new MyDBEntities;
int id = 111;
var item = context.MyTable.Where(i => i.id == id).Single();
```

This works fine but now I create a method I wish to use instead of the id check:

```
bool AreNear(string Adress, object Adress)
```

I'd like to use that way

```
 string adress = "...";
 var item = context.MyTable.Where(i => AreNear(i.adress,adress) ).Single();
```

but I get an error at the execution saying I can't use the method in my query 
is there a way to make it work?

Comment: You are using EF, the queries (Where) have to be converted to SQL...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to make it work.
The reason for this is that the LINQ query isn't really executed as .NET code but it is translated into SQL by the EF provider. This EF provider doesn't know how to translate `AreNear` into SQL, so it fails.

Comment: Then tell "why" or make it a comment.